# Trying to make certain text colored in sharepoint column

Tags: 2007, infopath, rich-text

I'm using Sharepoint 2007 and Infopath.

I've created a Document Library and populate the library using Infopath.  the Library is used as a log.. users enter log entries using an infopath form which has been published to the library.  when users open the form, they choose the type of log entry.. either a general log entry, error log entry, or informational log entry.

My question is dealing with the error log entry.   So, when a user selects the error log entry it opens certain fields in the form and they enter information dealing with the error. then submit the form to the library.

I have created columns in the library to store the data from the form.   In the main view, I've created one calculated column which I want to return selected pieces of info from the form.  I'm trying to have certain text displayed a certain color using the below formula which is in one Calculated Column:

=If([Log Type]="General",[Gen Remarks 1],If([Log Type]="Informational",[Gen Remarks 2],If([Log Type]="Error",""&"Equipment Affected:"&""&""&[Equipment Affected]&""&";"&""&""&"Brief Description:"&""&""&[Err Remarks]&""&";"&" "&""&"Remarks:"&""&""&[Gen Remarks 3]&""&";"&" "&""&"Who Contacted:"&""&""&[Contacted]&"",""))).   This formula works kinda, returning:  Equipment Affected: (in red)

```
              Server

               ;

               Brief Description:

               text text text

               ;

               Remarks: 

               text text text

               ;

               Who Contacted:
```

I would like to have it return:

```
                Equipment Affected:  Server;     ("Equipment Affected:" text is red)
                Brief Description: text text text;    ("Brief Description:" text is red)
                Remarks: Text text text;   ("Remarks:" text is red)
                Who Contacted:
```

formula works if I don't add the tags for font weight and color, but all is in black, but at least everything is in line.  Does this make sense?  Can anyone help??  would appreciate any help,

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution which would not demand any usage of SharePoint Designer or custom web part development is to use the "HTML Column" trick explained here http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/ and more examples here http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/06/16/html-calculated-column-solutions-for-sp-2010-part-iv/

You could really get to creative results with this approach.